# Function that reads data from input file and puts in array

Tags: c

I need to create a program that reads data from an input file and then will put it into the array.

Input file (values.dat): Left column represents heights, and right being weight.

```
60.0 125.0
54.0 98.0
62.0 145.0
67.0 155.0
59.0 100.0
```

The code that I have so far is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAXNUM 100

typedef struct person
{
  double height;
  double weight;
} Person;

int getData(FILE *input, Person people[], int);
void getAverages(Person people[], double *aveHeight, double *aveWeight, int numPeople);
void getStandardDevs(Person people[], double aveHeight, double aveWeight, 
                      double *stdHeight, double *stdWeight, int numPeople);


void main(void)
{
  char filename[] = "values.dat";
  FILE *input;
  Person people[MAXNUM];
  int numPeople;
  double aveHeight, aveWeight, stdHeight, stdWeight;

  numPeople = getData(input, people, MAXNUM);
  fclose(input);
  getAverages(people, &aveHeight, &aveWeight, numPeople);
  getStandardDevs(people, aveHeight, aveWeight, &stdHeight, &stdWeight, numPeople);

  printf("The average height is %lf\n", aveHeight);
  printf("The average weight is %lf\n", aveWeight);
  printf("The standard deviation of the heights is %lf\n", stdHeight);
  printf("The standard deviation of the weights is %lf\n", stdWeight);
}

int getData(FILE *input, Person people[], int max)
{
    int count = 0;
    int c;
    double h, w;
    input = fopen("values.dat", "r");
  if (input == NULL)
  {
    printf("Unable to open file\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  c = fscanf(input, "%lf %lf", &h, &w);
  while(c == 2)
  {
    people[count].height = h;
    people[count].weight = w;

   printf("height is %lf and weight is %lf", h, w);
    c = fscanf(input, "%lf %lf", &h, &w);
    count ++;
  }
  fclose(input);
}

void getAverages(Person people[], double *aveHeight, double *aveWeight, int numPeople)
{

}

void getStandardDevs(Person people[], double aveHeight, double aveWeight, double *stdHeight, double *stdWeight, int numPeople)
{


}
```

For the homework I have to complete the 3 functions but cant get the getData one to work for starters.

I get the error: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

If anyone has a fix for this please help.

Comment: Here is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757303/how-to-read-numbers-from-a-txt-file-in-c

Comment: `fclose(input);` - `input` pointer is unintiialized in main. And anyway, you could just remove it from `main`.

Answer (score 3):

The argument `input` of the function `getData` is a **copy of** passed value.

Therefore, change to `input` in the function `getData` won't affect
the variable `input` in the function `main`.

For that reason, the variable `input` in the function `main` remain uninitialized
when it is passed to function `fclose`.

This will invoke *undefined behavior* and have a big chance to get Segmentation fault.

To avoid Segmentation fault, you should remove this `fclose(input);` in the `main` function.

(Even if change in arguments would affect caller variables, calling `fclose` for already closed stream seems also bad.)

You are using the argument `input` not as an argument but as an local variable,
so removing the argument `input` and declaring it as a local variable will improve your code more.

Another point to improve your code is to use standard `int main(void)`
instead of implementation-defined `void main(void)`
unless you have some special reasons to use the implementation-defined one.